# Regex replace with PHP not working correctly

Tags: php, regex

My PHP code

```
$avatarFileName = './public/uploads/avatar\php17C_552334c997e50.png';
preg_replace('/^.\/public\/uploads\/avatar(\\|\/)/', "", $avatarFleName);
print_r($avatarFileName)
```

Above php code return string:

> ./public/uploads/avatar\php17C_552334c997e50.png

This is not correct string I want to have. The string I want is

> php17C_552334c997e50.png

I tested on site http://www.phpliveregex.com/ and it returns the correct string `php17C_552334c997e50.png` but not on my php application.

I am using PHP 5.5, anyone give me ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$result=preg_replace('/^.\\/public\\/uploads\\/avatar(\\\\|\\/)/', "", $avatarFleName);
```

Your regex is working fine.Just assign the return value to a variable and then access it.`replace` here is not `in place`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/108

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you don't delimit your regex with the two `/` like `/regexhere/` because it is already in a string delimiter (`'` in your case). So you can just do this:

```
$avatarFileName = './public/uploads/avatar\php17C_552334c997e50.png';
preg_replace('^.\/public\/uploads\/avatar(\\|\/)', "", $avatarFleName);
print_r($avatarFileName)
```

In most languages it's one of the two, either you have a string that starts and ends with `'` or `"`, **or** you have a *regex literal* where you start and end with `/`. It's never both.